LaTeXコード内のインデントをlstlisting環境内に反映させないようにする方法
私は文書内にプログラムのコードを埋め込むために、listingsパッケージのlstlisting環境内にコードを貼りつけました。
しかし、この方法をenumerate環境などの「LaTeXコードとしてのインデント」がされた場所で使うと、LaTeXコードとしてのインデントが貼り付けられるべきコードのインデントの一部と誤解されてしまい、埋め込んだコードが誤解された分だけPDF内で右に寄ってしまいます。
listing環境内のみ手動でLaTeXのインデントをなくせばこの問題は解決できるかと思ったのですが、次のコードのように指定しても、PDFに反映される時に下の画像のようにインデントが乱れてしまいます（しかも「かきくけこ」と「さしすせそ」が同じインデントなのにPDF内では位置が違います）。
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{ltjsarticle}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{listings}

\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{コード}
\lstset{
    frame=lines,
    numbers=left
}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\newcommand{\emphasis}[1]{\textsf{\textbf{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\newgeometry{top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,right=2.5cm,left=1.2cm}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\emphasis{\arabic*}]
    \item 1段階目のenumerate
          \begin{enumerate}[label=\emphasis{\arabic{enumi}.\arabic*}]
              \item 2段階目のenumerate
                    \begin{enumerate}[label=\emphasis{\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}.\arabic*}]
                        \item 3段階目のenumerate
                              \begin{enumerate}[label=\emphasis{\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}.\arabic{enumiii}.\arabic*}]
                                  \item 4段階目のenumerate\\
                                        \begin{lstlisting}[caption={位置のずれたlisting}]
あいうえお
    かきくけこ
    さしすせそ
          たちつてと
    なにぬねの
\end{lstlisting}
                              \end{enumerate}
                    \end{enumerate}
          \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}


\lstlistinginputというコマンドを使って外部ファイルを参照するようにすればインデントの問題を防げる事は分かったのですが、キャプションの付け方が分からないのでやはりlstlisting環境でなんとかコンパイラがインデントの誤解をしないようにするしかないと思います。
文章力が足りず長くなってしまいましたが、lstlisting環境内で貼りたいコードのインデントのみを出力させ、LaTeXコード内のインデントを無視させる方法を教えて頂きたいです。
どなたか詳しい方、ご教授お願いいたします。
使用しているLaTeXは LuaHBTeX 、バージョン1.18.0 (TeX Live 2024)です。

問題が再現しないので、問題が再現するようにプリアンブルまで含めた全体のコードを示していただきたいです。その際、問題の再現に必要のない箇所は削ってなるべく短いコードにしていただけると助かります。インデントがわかりやすいように図を添付するのはいいですが、テキストでも書いてもらえるとこちらでの再現がやりやすくて助かります。また、使用しているLaTeXエンジン（日本語なのでpLaTeXかupLaTeXかLuaTeXでしょうか）やTeX Liveのバージョンも明記した方が正確な回答が付きやすいと思います。

listingの中に日本語が含まれるのでlistingsパッケージではなくjlistingかplistings（個人的にはplistingsの方が新しいのでおすすめです）を使った方がよさそうです。もしかしたら、それだけで問題が解決するかもしれません。

@wtsnjp
wtsnjpさん、ご返信と親切なアドバイスありがとうございます。
質問文に配慮が足りず申し訳ありません。
足りなかった情報を補い、ご指摘いただいた内容通りに質問文を編集しました。
jlistingとplistingsについてですが、jlistingは見つかりませんでしたがjvlistingというパッケージは見つかりました。
しかしjvlistingでも結果は変わりませんでした。
plistingsの方は私が使用しているLatexがLuaHBTeXなので使えないようです。
教えて頂いてありがとうございました。

\lstinputlistingで外部ファイルから読み込むことで解決したということなので、それでよいと思いますが、lstlisting環境内へのベタ書きのまま「LaTeXソースとしてのインデント」を無視する方法もありますのでここに記しておきます。
lstlistingのオプションに与えることのできるgobbleキーがこの設定を行うためのもので、無視したいインデント幅を値として指定します（下記の例では34文字）。こうすることで、LaTeXソースとしてのインデントを崩さずに、意図通りのコードを掲載することができます。
\begin{enumerate}[label=\emphasis{\arabic*}]
    \item 1段階目のenumerate
          \begin{enumerate}[label=\emphasis{\arabic{enumi}.\arabic*}]
              \item 2段階目のenumerate
                    \begin{enumerate}[label=\emphasis{\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}.\arabic*}]
                        \item 3段階目のenumerate
                              \begin{enumerate}[label=\emphasis{\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}.\arabic{enumiii}.\arabic*}]
                                  \item 4段階目のenumerate\\
                                  \begin{lstlisting}[gobble=34, caption={位置のずれないlisting}]
                                  あいうえお
                                      かきくけこ
                                      さしすせそ
                                            たちつてと
                                      なにぬねの
                                  \end{lstlisting}
                              \end{enumerate}
                    \end{enumerate}
          \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}



以下は余談です。

（しかも「かきくけこ」と「さしすせそ」が同じインデントなのにPDF内では位置が違います）

私もTeX Live 2024のLuaHBTeXを利用して、質問に記載していただいたのとまったく同じLaTeXソースを処理してみましたが、これは再現しませんでした。エディタの方の設定で全角/半角スペースやタブ文字が混ざってしまっているということはないでしょうか……
また、コメントで日本語でlistingsしたい場合はjlistingやplistingsを使うとよいとお伝えしましたが、それは(u)pLaTeXの場合の話で、LuaTeX-jaを利用している場合はlistings読み込み時に内部で自動的にlltjp-listingsというパッチがあてられますので、こうした日本語専用パッケージの指定は不要なようです。

wtsnjpさん、度々詳しいアドバイスをありがとうございます。
gobbleオプションを使えば確かに全くインデントのずれない貼り付けができました!
これからは\lstinputlistingとwtsnjpさんの方法をコードの行数によって使い分けようと思います。
「かきくけこ」と「さしすせそ」のインデントについてはファイルを見直してみましたが全て半角スペースで統一されていました。でもPCごとエディタ(VSCode)を再起動するとインデントが狂わなくなったので恐らくこれも解決できたんだと思います。
何回も分かりやすい解説を、しかも環境を合わせた再現までして頂き、本当にありがとうございました。とても心強かったです。
それと、回答が役に立ったというボタンを押したのですが私の信頼度が足りていなくてできませんでした。ごめんなさい。

私は\lstlistinginputというコマンドではキャプションが付けられないと質問文に書いていましたが、\lstinputlistingというコマンドを使用すればキャプション付きで外部ファイルのコードを取り込めるという事が分かりました。
名前が似ているコマンドで全然気づきませんでした。
自己解決という形になり、お騒がせしてしまい申し訳ありません...
